# Unexpected behavior with connected UDP sockets

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

According to the manpage for `connect()`,

> If  the  socket sockfd is of type SOCK_DGRAM, then addr is the address to which datagrams are sent by default, and the only address from which datagrams are received.

I have Program A that calls `connect` on its socket with address 127.0.0.1 and port 1212 and Program B that calls `bind` on its socket with address IN_ADDRANY and port 1212.

When a packet is sent from program A using `send`, program B receives the packet and indicates the source address is in fact 127.0.0.1 using `recvfrom`.

The trouble comes when program B calls `connect` on its socket with address 127.0.0.1 and port 1212 after `bind`. Program B will no longer receive a packet when Program A sends a packet.

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this expected behavior?

I expect so (haha) -- I think the issue is that program B's `connect()` call has told B's UDP socket that it should only accept incoming UDP packets coming from 127.0.0.1:1212 -- but program A's packets are actually coming from 127.0.0.1:xxxxx, where xxxxx is some arbitrary available port that the networking stack implicitly bound program A's UDP socket to, because program A never called `bind()` explicitly (and yet A's UDP socket needs to be bound to a port before `send()` can work, since otherwise the OS doesn't know how to fill out the source-port field in the UDP packet header)

If that's the case, then your options are either to have program A explicitly `bind()` its socket to a different well-known port before calling `connect()` and `send()`, or to have program B somehow dynamically find out what port A is sending from before calling `connect()`, so that B can pass in the appropriate port number to `connect()`.

Or my favorite option, which is to avoid using `connect()` in conjunction with UDP sockets at all, and just use `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` instead.  I find that gives me much better control over UDP send/receive behavior, and therefore fewer headaches.

Comment: Oh, that makes so much sense, thank you very much! I did want to go the `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` route with all the flexibility it provides but I was thinking calling connect might offload some of the processing to the network interface, which would be great since I'm dealing with high bandwidth data.